# Currency * Time is returning an anomaly

Tags: excel, datetime, google-sheets, formula

I have a timesheet / invoice template I use in Excel / Google Spreadsheets (the anomaly is the same).

My equation is `Currency * Time`, for instance `£5 * 8 hours`, but this instead of `£40` returns `£1.67`. The currency cell is formatted as currency, the time cell as duration and the result cell also currency.

I've shared a Google Spreadsheet of the issue with commenting permissions here, if you'd like to edit the sheet you can always click file > make a copy - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UB3b6U3G6fh7wNZPfPB-gLaiaeJFEb_M0qGJJnxwv7g/edit#gid=1987667533

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel stores time as a fraction of a day. You need `Currency * Time * 24`, in this case `£5*08:00*24`.